# see yourself in a way that others might not see you, simply because

Tags: meaning-in-context

Kamala Harris said in her victory speech as follows:

- Dream with ambition, lead with conviction, and see yourself in a way that others might not see you,
  simply because they've never seen it before.

What does she mean by the last part which reads “see yourself in a way that others might not see you, simply because they’ve never seen it before?”

Comment: “... see yourself in a way [in which] others might not see you. The reason others might not see you in the way you discover is simply because they’ve never seen _anyone_ that way before.” I assume.

Answer (score 1):

It is a sort of reverse reference to the [Robert Burns poem "To a Louse"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_a_Louse) which says

> O wad some Pow'r the giftie gie us // To see oursels as ithers see us!

or in standard English

> Oh would some Power give us the gift // To see ourselves as others see us!

What Harris is saying is that you should believe that you can transcend the limitations placed on you by other people's perception of you. In other words "Don't let other people's prejudices define you".

Comment: Although it's related, I'm skeptical that it's a reference to Burns. The way I read it, Harris'  attempt to encourage self-confidence is only _similar_ to the _reverse_ of a really wonderful piece about our smallness among the fibers of the universe.

Comment: @Conrado I know what you mean, I didn't intend to imply that Harris was deliberately quoting Burns but the snippet of the verse is so deeply embedded in English speaking culture that I believe that most native English speakers are aware of it, even if they fon't realise that it's Burns (which Harris probably does)